# Перегрузка оператора, конкатенация

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, c++

Здравствуйте!

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при перегрузке оператора меняется начальные значения?

Например, есть строка А: "My name is" и строка B: "Alex". Создаем новую строку С, которая будет содержать содержимого  "строка A + строка B" C="My name is Alex".

Всё вроде бы работает, но почему-то меняется начальные значения строк А и В. Объясните, пожалуйста, где я ошибся и как правильно должен выглядеть код.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h> 
    using namespace std;

    class Stroka {
      private:char *str;
        int dlina;

      public:
         Stroka();
         Stroka(char *);             // Конструктор создании строки
         Stroka(Stroka & str);       // Конструктор копировании

        void vivod();

        Stroka operator +(Stroka b); // Конкатенация двух строк 
    };

    Stroka::Stroka()
    {
        dlina = 0;
    }

    // Конструктор создании строки 
    Stroka::Stroka(char *s)
    {
        dlina = strlen(s);
        str = new char[dlina + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < dlina; i++)
        str[i] = s[i];
        str[dlina] = '\0';
    }

    // Конструктор копировании 
    Stroka::Stroka(Stroka & t)
    {
        dlina = t.dlina;
        str = new char[dlina + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < dlina; i++)
        str[i] = t.str[i];
        str[dlina] = '\0';
    }

    void Stroka::vivod()
    {
        cout << "Stroka: " << str << " dlina: " << dlina << " simvolov" << endl;
    }

    // перегрузка оператора 
    // конкатенация двух строк  
    Stroka Stroka::operator +(Stroka b)
    {
        Stroka New[1];
        New[0].dlina = dlina + b.dlina;
        cout << "Operatorul + " << endl;
        New[0].str = str;
        strcat(New[0].str, b.str);
        return (New[0]);
    }

    void main()
    {
        // соединение двух строк  
        Stroka a("My name is ");
        Stroka b("Alex");
        cout << "Result:" << endl;
        a.vivod();
        b.vivod();
        cout << endl;

        Stroka c = a + b;
        c.vivod();
        cout << endl;
        getch();

        ///////////////////////////////

        cout << "Stroka a:" << endl;
        a.vivod();
        cout << "Stroka b:" << endl;
        b.vivod();
        cout << endl;

        getch();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хм, у вас тут есть и крупные ошибки, и мелкие недочёты.

Давайте пройдёмся по самой проблеме со сложением строк.

```
Stroka Stroka::operator +(Stroka b)
```

Тут строку `b` лучше передавать как `const Stroka& b`, чтобы избежать дорогого копирования.

```
{
    Stroka New[1];
```

а зачем массив? Почему не просто `Stroka New`?

```
    New[0].dlina = dlina + b.dlina;
    cout << "Operatorul + " << endl;
```

Пока в порядке...

```
    New[0].str = str;
```

Стоп! Грубая ошибка! Смотрите: `str` -- это же не сам текст, это *указатель* на текст! Так что эта команда приводит к тому, что теперь `New[0]` и текущий объект пользуются *одной и той же* строкой! И все изменения в строке для `New[0]` автоматически поменяют и строку для текущего объекта! Катастрофа!

```
    strcat(New[0].str, b.str);
```

Снова катастрофа: в `New[0].str` указатель на выделенный кусок памяти длиной `dlina`. Когда вы добавляете "в хвост" ещё одну строку, вы затираете случайное место в памяти.

```
    return (New[0]);
}
```

Как нужно было:

1. Определить, сколько понадобится памяти (вы это сделали правильно).
2. Выделить это количество памяти
3. Скопировать туда первую строку
4. В "хвост" скопировать вторую стороку.

Коротко о других ошибках:

1. В конструкторе по умолчанию вы не инициализируете указатель `str` (катастрофа!)
2. В остальных конструкторах лучше пользоваться `strcpy` (не так серьёзно)
3. У вас есть внутри аллоцируемые данные, так что вам нужен деструктор, иначе потерь памяти не избежать никак (серьёзная проблема)
4. У вас есть внутри аллоцируемые данные, так что вам нужен ещё перегруженный оператор присваивания (серьёзная проблема)
5. Согласно [правилу большой тройки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_%28C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), деструктор обязан быть виртуальным (тоже проблема, особенно если код будет использоваться вне учебного проекта).

---

Я бы сделал сложение так:

```
Stroka Stroka::operator +(const Stroka& b)
{
    Stroka result;
    delete result.str;
    result.dlina = dlina + b.dlina;
    result.str = new char[result.dlina + 1];
    strcpy(result.str, str);
    // копируем, начиная с конца предыдущей строки
    // поскольку мы знаем точно позицию, мы будем эффективнее, чем strcat
    strcpy(result.str + dlina, b.str);
    return result;
}
```

Не забудьте, этот код будет работать, если у вас правильно написан конструктор по умолчанию:

```
Stroka::Stroka()
{
    dlina = 0;
    str = new char[1];
    *str = 0;
}
```

Можно сделать чуть проще, введя приватный конструктор:

```
private:
Stroka(int length, char* payload);

// ...
Stroka::Stroka(int length, char* payload)
{
    dlina = length;
    str = payload;
}
```

и пользуясь им так:

```
Stroka Stroka::operator +(const Stroka& b)
{
    int newlength = dlina + b.dlina;
    char* newstr = new char[newlength + 1];
    strcpy(newstr, str);
    strcpy(newstr + dlina, b.str);
    return Stroka(newlength, newstr);
}
```

(Этот код можно оптимизировать, введя отдельный случай `str == NULL`, я знаю. Но для ТС надо сначала разобраться в простом варианте.)

Comment: Спасибо вам за столь развёрнутый ответ, но не могли бы вы написать правильный вариант кода? Пожалуйста

Comment: Правильный вариант написан в заголовочном файле <string> стандартной библиотеки. Ну или в <cstring> заголовок strcat() если любите антиквариат. А то что у вас здесь даже на govnokod.ru заминусуют, слишком уныло. Хотя если посмотреть с той точки зрения что вы пытаетесь определить конкатенацию строк и одновременно подключаете заголовочный файл в котором она уже определена то получается вполне ничего экземлпяр, но всё равно унылый.

Comment: @alexl1720p: написал более правильный вариант.

Comment: @alexl1720p: и ещё более правильный :)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал 

(учитывая дальнейшее развитие класса, дополнение его новыми методами (операторами), которые могут не только увеличивать, но и уменьшать dlina)

кроме поля dlina в классе Stroka завести еще и поле razmer, в котором хранится реально выделенное количество байт (на них указывает str). И перейти от new/delete к malloc/**realloc**/free. 


Использование realloc может заметно повысить эффективность конкатенации.

--

Однако, не могу не заметить, что (конечно IMHO) переопределение операторов это **зло**.

Comment: @avp: `realloc` -- классная идея! Спасибо, я не догадался сразу. В текущем коде править не буду, чтобы не противоречить другим методам.

Я бы посоветовал ТС записать её на будущее и применить -- после дописывания и отладки текущей реализации.

Comment: Спасибо вам добрые люди за помощь и за советы, низкий вам поклон.

Comment: @alexl1720p: пожалуйста! Читайте хорошие книги, развивайте ваши умения, совершенствуйтесь. Успехов вам!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, здесь нужна перегрузка бинарного оператора +.

```
Stroka Stroka::operator +(Stroka a, Stroka b).
```

В вашем варианте вначале B добавляется к A, затем A приравнивается к C.

Comment: @Ильшат: в C++ можно и так, и так, либо instance-метод с одним аргументом, либо статический с двумя.